# How to get fields_for to create new objects and many-to-many relationships simultaneously?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, fields-for

I've been following through these Railscasts and trying to amend the code so it works with Rails 3:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-2

http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-3

I am trying to create Groups, Users and Memberships (the many-to-many relationships) simultaneously. People can add users to the group as they create it and then I want it to route through to a view of the group with all the members. I can get memberships to create just fine but having trouble creating users and associating them the group. My code currently looks like this:

## Group.rb

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships

  attr_accessible :group_name

  def user_attributes=(user_attributes)
    user_attributes.each do |attributes|
      users.build(attributes)
    end
  end
end
```

## Membership.rb

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :groups
  belongs_to :users
end
```

## User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
end
```

## groups_controller.rb

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def create #todo test for number of groups they're already in before creation
    @group = Group.new(params[:group])
    @group.memberships.build(:user_id => current_user.id)
    #@group..build

    respond_to do |format|
      if @group.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@group, :notice => 'Group was successfully created and user added...?') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My form looks like this:

[image: The form creator]

Which is created by:

## views/groups/new.html.rb

```
<h1>New group</h1>

<%= form_for(@group) do |f| %>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Create a new group</legend>
  <%= render 'shared/group_error_messages', :object => f.object %>  
  <div class="clearfix">
    <%= f.label :group_name %>
    <div class="input">
      <%= f.text_field :group_name %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="users">
    <%= render :partial => 'user', :collection => @group.users %>
  </div>

</div>
<p><%= add_user_link "Add a member" %></p>


<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit :value => 'Create your group', :class => 'btn success'%>

  <!-- todo test for if they already have a group...-->
</div>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

## views/groups/_user.html.rb

```
<div class="user">
  <%= fields_for :user do |f| %>
    <div class="clearfix">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <div class="input">
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <%= f.label :number %>  
    <div class="input">
      <%= f.text_field :number %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_function "remove", "$(this).up('.user').remove()" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks *very, very* much in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stumbled upon a fairly out of date Railscast it seems.  Some age very well... this one not as much.  What you're looking for is a [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) which was introduced in rails 2.3.

Group model:

```
#app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships

  accepts_nested_atrributes_for :users
end
```

Group Controller:

```
#app/controllers/groups_controller.rb
Class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @group = Group.new(params[:group)
    @group.save ? redirect_to(@group) : render("new")
  end
end
```

New Group action:

```
  <!-- Giving you the important changes only -->
  <div id="users">
    <%= render :partial => 'user', :collection => @group.users, :locals => { :form => f } %>
  </div>
```

User partial:

```
<div class="user">
  <%= form.fields_for :user do |f| %>
```

As a general rule of thumb, you should use more descriptive names for your form block variables, especially with nested forms.

Comment: Hi Patrick. Thanks a lot for your answer. I've changed the name of the block variables and brought the partial into the main form for testing purposes. I'm getting this error:   Processing by GroupsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1Z9IUg7pkg4Xqxa97TI0iqHiUOJNAdqLb04P5iyuKMY=", "group"=>{"group_name"=>"asdfasdf", "user"=>{"user_name"=>"happy", "user_number"=>"07777888995"}}, "commit"=>"Create your group"}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user
  AREL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "groups" ("group_name", "cre

Comment: You may need to go the route of blacklisting certain fields in app/models/group.rb with "attr_protected" instead of whitelisting with "attr_accessible".  The nested attributes appear to be protected by accident.